# How do I connect my wallet to opensea using web3.py

Tags: ether, wallets, nft, web3.py, opensea

I get that u can transfer eth using web3.py but is that any way to connect opensea and sign massage

Answer (score 1):

First, connect to the Mainnet, you can use infura links:

```
from web3 import Web3

#INFURA HTTP API
infura_url='https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/29547...' #your uri
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))
```

Than connect your personal wallet by:

```
account = w3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount(PRIVATE_KEY)
w3.eth.defaultAccount = account
```

And for the last step you'll need to specify your desired contract address and ABI

```
contract = w3.eth.contract(address=CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi=CONTRACT_ABI)
```

And now you can sign transactions and interact with contracts :)